# How can I handle elements with class imported from mySQL with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am newbie in PHP and I am trying to create a reaction system like Facebook but I'm stuck on how do I select an element whose class(`class=""`) contains the id of the current post. To be more clear the button of the reactions has a class which is equal to this: `class="reaction-toggle--'+postId+'"`. I use two different files to read the posts and handle the reactions. In the first file I use AJAX to read the posts from mySQL and in the second I am calling AJAX again but now I am reading only the IDs of the posts in order to trigger the reactions dialog.

I thought that it might help if I use AJAX and I tried the following code:
**PHP**

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include "conn.php";
//session start
session_start();
//retrieve user
if(isset($_SESSION["userId"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["profile_image"]) && isset($_SESSION["first_name"]) && isset($_SESSION["last_name"])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ID FROM posts GROUP BY(ID)");

    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}else {
    echo "It doesn't work";
}
?>
```

And **Javascript**

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

var method = "GET";

var url = "../new/php/handle_posts_details.php";

var asynchronous = true

ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous)

//sending ajax request
ajax.send()


//receiving response from php
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  
      //converting JSON to array
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //html value for posts
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var ID = data[i].ID;

        //Open and send reactions
      document.querySelector('.reaction-toggle--'+data[i].ID+'').addEventListener("mouseenter",function(e){
        document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "block";
      });
      document.querySelector('.reaction-toggle--'+data[i].ID+'').addEventListener("mouseleave",function(e){
        document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "none";
      });
      document.querySelector('.reaction-toggle--'+data[i].ID+'').addEventListener("mouseenter",function(e){
        document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "block";
      });
      document.querySelector('.reaction-toggle--'+data[i].ID+'').addEventListener("mouseleave",function(e){
        document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "none";
      });

      //Send Reactions
      }
      console.log(data);
  }
}
```

The posts are read perfectly but the problem occurs when it comes to the reactions. The error in above code is that it shows me: `querySelector` is null (But the postId exists). Is there a way I can solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
Because the html that is generated is too many lines I am adding just the reaction button. Here it is:

```
<a id="default-like-'.$ID.'" href="#/" class="post__action post__action--reaction reaction reaction__toggle reaction-toggle--'.$ID.' reaction-emoticon-0 js-reaction-toggle" style="display: none;">
              <span>Like</span>
              </a>
```

**EDIT 2:**
This is a sample of the json because there are also too many data.
Here it is: `[{"ID":"36"},{"ID":"54"},{"ID":"55"},{"ID":"57"},{"ID":"58"},{"ID":"60"}]`

Comment: Hi Brad, could you please share the HTML generated by your code so we can see why the JS isnt working?

Comment: Thanks @Brad, could you also supply the JSON string generated from the PHP file?

Comment: @OliverKucharzewski Of course, I added the json too.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use the data attribute instead of classes?

Comment: @ES How could I do that? I am newbie as I said above, so sorry if it is stupid question.

Comment: Hey @BradCruise - i've included E S's suggestion in my answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to render PHP in your view; but I would suggest you consider using GET requests to pull the data you need, and then rendering it using Javascript.

If you use your PHP code to generate the reactions you need, you can actually iterate through each one and generate it on your front-end. This would be a lot cleaner.

First of all, try to turn your identifier into a variable.

```
let data_id = data[i].ID;
let selector = '[data-id="' + data_id + '"]';
```

Once the selector is set, you can use this in future, and as opposed to changing multiple lines of code to update the selector, you can change one.

Now we can use this code to generate lots of reactions.

You will need a div to contain these reactions.

```
<div id='parent-container'></div>
```

And we can start loading this div up using the existing loop.

```
let post_obj = `<a id="default-like" href="#/" class="post__action post__action--reaction reaction reaction__toggle reaction-toggle reaction-emoticon-0 js-reaction-toggle" style="display: none;" data-id="${data_id}">
              <span>Like</span>
              </a>`;


// Wait for element to render 
setTimeout(() => {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.innerHTML += post_obj;
}, 500);
```

Once this object is loaded in, you can assign event listeners to it:

```
 document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener("mouseenter",function(e){
    document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "block";
  });
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener("mouseleave",function(e){
    document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "none";
  });
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener("mouseenter",function(e){
    document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "block";
  });
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener("mouseleave",function(e){
    document.querySelector('.container').style.display = "none";
  });
```

Notice how using one variable is a lot cleaner.

Comment: Hey, it gives me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: element is null`

Comment: You would have to wait for the element to render; is it showing on the screen?
You can try putting it in 
setTimeout(() => {
//Put code here
}, 500)

And see if it works. (P.S. there are better ways of doing it than setTimeout but this will get us started) :)

Comment: Also check that data-id is correctly set in the rendered HTML using Chrome code inspector - I wrote this code without testing it.. i trust the logic will roughly work

Comment: I think I found what is wrong. You code is working perfect I just miss something. Now it seems to work. Thank you!!!